# Make a heading in beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, themes

I would like to have the ability to add "headings" to content in my beamer slides.
By heading I just mean slightly larger text that automatically breaks the row and adds some margins to the surrounding text.
Basically something that is exactly like the `\section` command when writing an article.

I have so far done this using the `block` environment like

```
\begin{block}{The heading}
The content goes here.
\end{block}
```

which worked with my previous theme since the block background was the same as the slide background.
But in my new theme I want to have the usual colored boxes, so some other method is required.

I tried implementing a new `headingblock` environment that is basically a block environment with new colors:

```
\newenvironment{headingblock}[1]{%
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=white, fg=black}
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=white, fg=liu_blue}
  \begin{block}{#1}}{\end{block}}
```

The problem is that everything else inside the block is affected by the `\setbeamercolor` calls which means I can't have another block inside the headingblock.
Also it feels kind of hackish.

What is the best way to implement this?

**Edit**
To be extra clear, I am not looking for a frame title, but subheadings within the frame. Something like:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{The slide}

  \myheading{The first heading}
  Some text and stuff that goes with the first heading

  \myheading{Second heading}
  More stuff goes here.
\end{frame}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Ok, I thought the `\framesubtitle{...}` command would solve this. But there can only be one subtitle to every frame...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define your own block structure in a similar way in which beamer defines `exampleblock` or `alertblock`, and set the `block title` and `block body` colors for this new block as desired. The original definitions can be found in the file `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`. Here's a definition of such a block that you can adjust according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment<>{headingblock}[1]{%
    \begin{actionenv}#2%
      \def\insertblocktitle{#1}%
      \par%
      \mode<presentation>{%
        \setbeamercolor{heading}{fg=black,bg=yellow}
      }%
     \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=orange,bg=structure}
     %\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=green,bg=orange} % to customize the colors of the block body
      \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
    {\par%
      \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
    \end{actionenv}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{headingblock}{A test heading}
Some test text.
\end{headingblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are not interested in a block and want something simpler, you can do something along the following lines (again, adjust the settings according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand\myheading[1]{%
  \par\bigskip
  {\Large\bfseries#1}\par\smallskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some test text.
\myheading{A test heading}
Some test text.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I finally settled on using something similar to your final example. Thanks!

Comment: And if you want to move your heading little up , You can use \vspace{-4 cm} \myheading{Solar cells} along with the above mentioned solution.